# When I try to "copy" an object in Inkscape I get an error about UniConvertor

Tags: inkscape, linux

I'm running Inkscape 0.92 on Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch).

When I try to "copy" an object in Inkscape I get an error about UniConvertor not beeing installed.

> You need to install the UniConvertor software.
>   For GNU/Linux: install the package python-uniconvertor.
>   For Windows: download it from
>   https://sk1project.net/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor&op=download
>   and install into your Inkscape's Python location

I get the following windows displayed as a result of the error in the given order:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem was not in Inkscape. In Lubuntu 19.04 I had to uninstall Qlipper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer:

Closing "xfce4-clipman" solved this problem for me.

## More text:

Yes, here I answer my own question and actually I just created this question in order to answer it myself in an attempt do document this problem for people who might run into the same problem.

In an old [mailing list entry](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=553456#60) form March 2011 someone suggested that if you have "xfce4-clipman" running this might be the problem and closing "xfce4-clipman" might solve the problem.

> I've found that This error appears when xfce4-clipman-plugin. If you close
>   or kill this application, Inkscape does not complain.
>
> I think the problem is not Inkscape, but clipman plugin in this case.

I tried, and it solved my problem. Super weired for me and I can't explain how those two would be related, but just closing "xfce4-clipman" solved the problem for me.

I also don't understand why the problem is still around after nine years.

Comment: You should accept this answer, too. Otherwise the case stays open and "as no solutions given" until it gets closed for some reason such as "this has nothing to do with graphics and design" . Consider to write a bug report.

Comment: You're right, and I tried, but StackExchange tells me "You can accept your own answer in 2 days."
I'll try to remember to do so ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm stealing the comment from user144509 as it solved the issue for me.

On Lubuntu 19.04/19.10, the problem comes from Qlipper, which probably mangles the copy to the clipboard. The solution is to either terminate the "qlipper" process or completely uninstall the package.

Comment: Any idea is it Lubuntu bug, Ubuntu bug, Inkscape bug or Qlipper bug? I am tempted to report it, but I am not sure where.

Comment: The Inkscape projet seems to be aware of it. The discussion here mentions the issue: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/575 There is an open bug report, but it has not been resolved yet: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/418242

Comment: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/575 seems to be final one after round of migrations (initial https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/418242 to https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/359 and then to https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/575 with latest commit activity in 2021-03-06 - so earlier versions still with  bug is not reason to report it again)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happens on Ubuntu 18.04, where I got 3 different messages boxes (that all open one after another stealing focus from the terminal window every time):

```
This extension requires at least one non-empty layer
```

```
No paths where found. Please convert all objects you want to save into paths
```

and

```
You need to install the UniConvertor software.
For GNU/Linux: install the package python-uniconvertor.
For Windows: download it from
https://sk1project.net/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor&op=download
and install into your Inkscape's Python location
```

The problem went away when I installed yudit:

```
sudo apt install yudit
```

as this provides the `uniconv` binary that inkscape seems to need.